# Could not able to set and get cookies in jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to set and get cookies in jQuery but cant read them.

```
var Objdata = {};
Objdata.username = username;
Objdata.password = password;
var urls = "gallries.aspx/CheckUser";
alert(username + password);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: urls,
    data: "{'username':'" + username + "','password':'" + password + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.d == true) {
            alert(username);
            $.cookie("loggedInUser", username);
            alert($.cookie("loggedInUser"));
            alert('Login Success');

            _loginMsg.addClass("success").removeClass("error");
            _loginMsg.html("Login was successful!");
            $('.user_login').animate({ 'top': '-165px' }, 800);
            $('#modal').fadeOut(500);                         
        }
```

In the `if` block I am setting and trying to get in next step.

Comment: What does the `alert()` show? Are you sure the `success` handler is being run? Have you checked if the cookie exists in the browser's settings? Have you included the cookie plugin? And checked that it loaded properly? We need more detail here.

Comment: yes.. Success is running thats y i am getting first alert username but after that now happening any thing..

Comment: I included this plugin in head part. <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.cookie/1.3.1/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

Comment: If nothing happens after that first alert it sounds like  you have an error; check the console

Comment: first alert mean in success i have 'alert(username);' ..its runn then  nothing happening..

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Or there could be something else coming in response.

Comment: @ShekharPankaj OP says he's sees the first alert, though.

Comment: `alert(username + password);` this alert could be the first one?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the first alert  is before ajax call

Comment: @Azaad I know - if only one alert shows execution has stopped. This generally means you have an error - *check the console*

Comment: try `document.cookie="username=John Doe; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC";`

Comment: @Azaad , add error block or open Browser console or put debugger in browser...and update then ..what you see there

Comment: I think your ajax call is not happening (incorrect url or server error), the alert you see is the first alert before/outside the success

Comment: in console Thes Errors Got....Uncaught ReferenceError: jquery is not defined
Uncaught error:bootstrap's javascript requires jquery
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
uncaught TypeError: $.cookie is not a function

Comment: Now again checked this error throwing..$.cookie is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try by javascript its no need any lab files

/*for setparticular cookie*/

```
var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (24*30 * 1000));
            expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
            document.cookie = "gallId=" + imageId + expires;
```

/*for get particular cookie*/

```
var gallId = getCookie('gallId');
                    function getCookie(name) {
                        var nameEQ = name + "=";
                        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
                        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                            var c = ca[i];
                            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
                            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
alert(gallId);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try :**

```
success:{
    setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays);
    }
```

**Function To Set Cookies (Eg)**

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
```

**Function To Get Cookies (Eg)**

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Reffrence URL : [W3school](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Comment: pasting two pieces of code you found on the internet (which the asker doesn't even need) is not an answer.

Comment: This is not proper question also .. Its Off topice Question  ..Asking For Coding HElp

Answer (score -1):

Use COOKIE plugin:**http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/**

***Set a cookie examples***

$.cookie("example", "foo"); // Sample 1

$.cookie("example", "foo", { expires: 7 }); // Sample 2

$.cookie("example", "foo", { path: '/admin', expires: 7 }); // Sample 3

***Get a cookie examples***

alert( $.cookie("example") );

***Delete the cookie***

$.removeCookie("example");

Comment: that means you havenot add >Jquery Library Properly

Comment: I have added this <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.cookie/1.3.1/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

Comment: Write down the `<Script>` after jquery library file

Comment: I did as you mentioned but again same error showing,,

Comment: I added your jquery file <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

Comment: `<head>
  <script src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="path/to/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
</head>`

Comment: Do you try `<script src="path/to/jquery.js"></script> <script src="path/to/jquery.cookie.js"></script><script>// your code</script>`

Comment: If Its Not working Then Try To Implement it with my answer ... Which Is Javascript based .. it will be work 100% ... Also It will reduce one libray from  your site and decrese load time